# Linux HTML file server

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, html, file-server

I'm building a file server using Ubuntu.

I want to setup an HTML based file upload/download system where I can create accounts for a few users and allow each user access certain folders. So that the user would open it like a webpage using a web browser and then uploads and downloads files, not needing special setup for the computer.

Is there a ready made solution for that purpose? Will I have to code it?

Thanks

Comment: Why not WebDAV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can set up a webserver with PHP and MySQL (Ubuntu Server can do it mostly automatically), you can use one of a number of prebuilt PHP solutions:

- http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/ (pretty basic)
- http://pfn.sourceforge.net/ (pretty fancy)
- http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/ (single-script, dead simple, a favorite of mine. not open source, but free for personal use and only US$20 for business use)

Check out Ubuntu Server's server set-up wizard. It'll get you going with Apache and MySQL pretty quickly, with a decent default configuration. Be cautious if you plan on exposing this to the internet, though.